# StrictMode giving warning when I collect from Coroutines Flow?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Can somebody please explain why StrictMode giving me warning when I collect in Main thread?

I have strictMode enabled in my application class file.

```
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .detectDiskReads()
                .detectDiskWrites()
                .detectNetwork() 
                .penaltyLog()
                .build()
        )
```

Here I launching a coroutine to collect from the Flow.

```
binding.buttonOne.setOnClickListener {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
       simple().flowOn(Dispatchers.IO).collect {
             Log.d(TAG, "in collect block: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
             binding.flowExampleone.text="$it"
             log(it.toString())
         }
    }
}
```

```
 fun simple() = flow<Int> {
        for (i in 1..3) {
            Log.d(TAG, "in simple block: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            delay(1000)
            emit(i)
        }
    }

    fun log(message: String) {
        Log.d("mytag", message)
    }
```

But when i run it. The StrictMode is giving warning.

```
D/StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=34 ms: android.os.strictmode.DiskReadViolation
```

Comment: There does not appear to be any disk I/O from that flow. How have you concluded that this `StrictMode` message is tied to this flow?